# Codeception: I can see a link, but can't click it

Tags: selenium, xpath, codeception, acceptance-testing

I am working through learning Codeception, and have run into something I think is strange.

```
// This works
$I->see('Secure Check Out', '(//a[contains(text(),"Secure Check Out")])[2]');

// This does not
$I->click('Secure Check Out', '(//a[contains(text(),"Secure Check Out")])[2]');
```

Couldn't click "Secure Check Out","(//a[contains(text(),"Secure Check Out")])[2]":
Link or Button or CSS or XPath 'Secure Check Out' was not found on page.

Running against Firefox via Selenium WebDriver. What do I have to do to get this to work?

Here's roughly the HTML that's relevant.

```
<div class="mobile-only">
<a href="/responsive/ajax/modals/check-out/login.php" class="secure-checkout button blue bordered small modal-open">Secure Check Out</a>
</div>

<div class="secure-checkout-button threecol last mobile-hide">
<div class="pull-right">
<a style="background-color: transparent;" href="/responsive/ajax/modals/check-out/login.php" class="button blue bordered small modal-open">Secure Check Out</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tested the selector? Can you also provide some html of the element?

Comment: @Saifur I pulled that selector from the Selenium IDE in Firefox. Not sure what you mean by tested. It works with the IDE, and it works in Codeception, with the see call. The page I'm testing is very complex, but I've dropped the HTML as best I can in the question.

Comment: See also this other question, which has the same problem (see() and click() behaving differently) but a different solution because it wasn't using xpath: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47094032/codeception-cant-click-on-element-it-has-seen-just-before/68580465#68580465

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like it's just because the `see` function allows two parameters and `click` does only one in case of `xpath`. So, according to [this](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#click) the following should work

```
$I->click('(//a[contains(text(),"Secure Check Out")])[2]');
```